# g++ will not link to library in /usr/lib/

Tags: c++, cmake

I've created a library and installed it in /usr/lib (using cmake) eg.:

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX /usr/) 
target_link_libraries(ssd1306)
set_target_properties(ssd1306 PROPERTIES   VERSION 1.0.0   SOVERSION 1 )
install(TARGETS ssd1306 DESTINATION lib)   
install(FILES ${SSD1306_HEADERS} DESTINATION include)
```

This worked fine and the library is present on my filesystem:
The library:

ls -l /usr/lib/libssd1306*

```
/usr/lib/libssd1306.so -> libssd1306.so.1
/usr/lib/libssd1306.so.1 -> libssd1306.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib/libssd1306.so.1.0.0
```

And the header:

ls -l /usr/include/ssd1306.h

```
/usr/include/ssd1306.h
```

Then I wrote a program which use the library (again using cmake):

```
target_link_libraries(ssd1306-info libssd1306)
```

But for some reason it will not link to my library at compile time:

**/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibssd1306**

The header file was found and the object file was created, but linking failed.

Of course /usr/lib/ is in g++ search path:

```
g++ -print-search-dirs
```

install: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/
programs: =/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/bin/
libraries: =/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Try running `make` in verbose mode to see how it attempt to build your program. You do it by adding the `VERBOSE=1` argument when running `make`.

Comment: I think you need to update the library cache by running ldconfig.

Comment: Shouldn't it be only `target_link_libraries(ssd1306-info ssd1306)`?

Comment: Are you running into 32-bit vs 64-bit library issues?

Comment: Have you double checked all these symlinks?

Comment: verbose=1 gave this output: /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/ssd1306-info.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++      CMakeFiles/ssd1306-info.dir/ssd1306-info.cpp.o  -o ssd1306-info -rdynamic -llibssd1306 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibssd1306
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: skypjack: when I try target_link_libraries(ssd1306-info ssd1306) it complains about 'arduino' for some reason: CMakeFiles/ssd1306-info.dir/ssd1306-info.cpp.o: In function `main':
ssd1306-info.cpp:(.text+0x1c93): undefined reference to `arduino'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Jonathan Leffler: "file" says: /usr/lib/libssd1306.so.1.0.0: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=8a704c12c86bbe40d443183c8fabefb9f559a035, not stripped    and file on target:  ./CMakeFiles/ssd1306-info.dir/ssd1306-info.cpp.o: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped

Comment: Mati: Yes - they look nice, pointing to the right thing as far as I can tell (see post) and with a cyanide color

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

Both the library and the executable where linking in the same object (.o) file.

The 'arduino' stuff was about a external variable which should not be there (copy-and-paste code issue).